# How to use variables in Backbone events object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Currently my code looks like this:

```
events: {
    'click .update-url': 'update_url',
    'click .show-password': 'show_password'
},
```

but for touch devices I want to use `touchstart` instead of `click` as the event hence I want to use variables like this:

```
var click_event = is_touch_device ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

...

events: {
    click_event + ' .update-url': 'update_url',
    click_event + ' .show-password': 'show_password'
},
```

But it doesn't work. How to use variables in this way while still using the event's object in Backbone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone has the same issue, I fixed it this way:

```
    events: function() {
        var _events = {};
        _events[click_event + ' a.menu-toggle'] = 'toggle_menu';
        _events[click_event + ' a.close-menu, a.authenticate'] = 'close_menu';
        _events[click_event + ' ul.menu-links > li.dd'] = 'toggle_sub_menu';
        _events[click_event + ' #search-form-lg button'] = 'expand_search';
        return _events;
    },
```

Comment: A lot of "properties" in Backbone can also be functions: ["The `events` property may also be defined as a function that returns an **events** hash, to make it easier to programmatically define your events, as well as inherit them from parent views."](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents).